# how to get percentage change of distance due to latitude alone?

Tags: java

I got a java program to find the distance between two latitude and longitude points using haversine formula and its working..but I need to find by what percentage does the latitude  change altered  the distance.

Comment: add in your code, makes things easier.

Comment: Calculate the latitude distance, making the longitude the same for both points.  Divide the latitude distance by the actual distance.

Comment: Take the partial derivative of the haversine formula with respect to latitude.

Comment: I don't think you've defined your problem clearly enough.  Do you mean  you want the distance between the two lines of latitude, divided by the distance between the two points?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for your answer, it worked.